# SLES License Migration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, suse

Recently i migrated an SLES image from AWS to GCP and when i tried to update the repositories using the command  `zypper ref` I realized that the zypper was not working since the instance wasn't properly registered as a Cloud SLES.

I've created a new fresh SLES instance in GCP to check the zypper configurations and realised in `/etc/hosts` there was a entry for the GCP SMT servers.

I went back to the migrated compute engine in GCP, updated the /etc/hosts and ran the following commands:

`SUSEConnect --status`

`SUSEConnect --cleanup`

`/usr/sbin/registercloudguest`

And it didn't work.

I even tried by replicating the machine image with the flag of `--licenses` via gcloud https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/create but still no success.

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are migrating the instances to Google Cloud.

Following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.11/how-to/migrate-aws-to-gcp/overview#prepare_your_linux_vms) will have you to migrate the instance also found this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.11/how-to/prepare-vms-servers/preparing-linux-vms#suse-sles) to prepare the instance

I have a question, you add the AWS credentials for continue the migration?

To define cloud credentials:

1.Sign in to your Migrate for Compute Engine Manager as apiuser.

2.Click the **Source Cloud** icon.

3.Sign in with the credentials you created when creating the Manager.

4.Click the **Cloud Credentials** tab.

5.Click **Create** and select **AWS** from the cloud provider drop-down menu.

6.In the **Create New Credentials** dialog, enter values to configure credentials:

-**Cloud provider** -- Select AWS.

-**Credentials Name** -- Enter a name for this credential's configuration.

-**Region** -- Select the region where you want this credential created.

-**Access key** -- Enter the access key for the IAM account you created earlier.

-**Secret key** -- Enter the secret key you created earlier.

7.Click **OK**.

If you need to add more Cloud details use this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.11/how-to/migrate-aws-to-gcp/configure-aws-as-a-source#creating_a_cloud_details_object_for_aws_migrations)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Yes i did use Migrate, and i prepared the machines, and defined the cloud credential, but since this a SLES with builtin license, i come to understand that what i want is option 2 here:  https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/compute-engine-licensing-explained  

Since i already migrated and the only original image i have are snapshots in GCP, do you know a way to implement option 2 in an already migrated image in GCP?

Comment: I have been searching and found this documentation https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/bringing-your-own-licenses maybe you can do this,  instead the other step, I don't think you can unless you rebuild because the license is injected into the metadata when its migrated and there's no way that I'm aware of that can change that

Answer (score 0):

Please login to the instance using SSH, if the SLES asks for the license key, to add the key you can run yast [1] or SUSEConnect [2] commands. For more information please follow the [documentation](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000018564).

1- yast scc

2- SUSEConnect --url=https://scc.suse.com  -e company@example.com -r YOUR_CODE

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know how to get a licence CODE since in GCP (or AWS) the SLES code is handled by the provided (AWS or GCP) when creating a new instance. Both on GCP and AWS the SLES license fee is included when an instance is launched. 
So, my question is: How can we generate or get a new SLES license code without paying new fees to SUSE and instead use the partnership between SUSE and GCP?